# Последовательная проверка элементов списка, поиск пути

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите пожалйста. Пытаюсь написать алгоритм для находжения пути (размер пути не важен). Есть конечная точка возле игрока, так же есть начальная точка от куда путь начинается, и еще есть точки соединяющие начальную и конечную точку. Проблема в том что у каждой точки есть свой список (список соседей к которым можно прийти из этой точки). Пробовал создавать новый список и добавлять в него точку ее соседей, и так пока мы не дойдем до крайней точки. Но проблема такая, как сделать последовательную проверку каждого списка, то есть 1я точка 1й сосед (и если есть его сосед, и тд.), после когда дошли до конца, 1я точка 2й сосед и тд. пока не придем к конечной точке. Пытался через IEnumerator, особо дельного ничего не получилось. пройденные точки учитывал, что бы не добавлять их повторно.

Comment: Списоком соседей называется список смежности. А алгоритм вы описали - обычный поиск в ширину, только для каждой вершины/ точки надо указывать откуда в неё пришли